# Xtext validation across (unreferenced) files

Tags: xtext

I am struggling to validate (non-duplication) globally, across multiple files that do not explicitly reference each other.

Consider the standard initally-generated grammar

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Model:
    greetings+=Greeting*;

Greeting:
    'Hello' name=ID '!';
```

It is simple to validate that no file contains greeting for the same name.

```
package org.xtext.example.mydsl.validation

import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.Check
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.Greeting
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.Model
import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.MyDslPackage

class MyDslValidator extends AbstractMyDslValidator {

    public static val LOCALLY_DUPLICATE_NAME = 'LOCALLY_DUPLICATE_NAME'

    @Check
    def checkGreetingLocallyUnique(Greeting greeting) {
            for(greeting_ : (greeting.eContainer as Model).greetings) {
                if(greeting!==greeting_ && greeting.name==greeting_.name) {
                    warning('Greeting duplication', 
                    MyDslPackage.Literals.GREETING__NAME,
                    LOCALLY_DUPLICATE_NAME)
                }
            }
    }

}
```

- I do not understand how to validate non-duplication against *all the files* known to the global-index.

The stub of the method is

```
@Check
def checkGreetingGloballyUnique(Greeting greeting) {
        for(greeting_ : /*???*/ ) {
            if(greeting!==greeting_ && greeting.name==greeting_.name) {
                warning('Global Greeting duplication', 
                MyDslPackage.Literals.GREETING__NAME,
                GLOBALLY_DUPLICATE_NAME)
            }
        }
}
```

- How do I get access to the global index from within the validator?

Comment: I am trying to see if changing the scope provider is the way to go.

Comment: No. But injecting IResourceDescriptions might help!

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way for a local duplicate validation is to enable it in the workflow and regenerate the language (this does not check locally though)

```
        validator = {
            composedCheck = "org.eclipse.xtext.validation.NamesAreUniqueValidator"
        }
```

to search the index

```
@Inject
IContainer.Manager containermanager;

@Inject
ResourceDescriptionsProvider resourceDescriptionsProvider;

public .... getAllEntitiesFor( EObject eObject ) {
    ....
    IResourceDescriptions resourceDescriptions = resourceDescriptionsProvider.getResourceDescriptions( eObject.eResource() );
    IResourceDescription resourceDescription = resourceDescriptions.getResourceDescription( eObject.eResource().getURI() );
    List<IContainer> visiblecontainers = containermanager.getVisibleContainers( resourceDescription, resourceDescriptions );
    for (IContainer container : visiblecontainers) {
        for (IEObjectDescription eobjectDescription : container.getExportedObjects()) {
            EObject eObjectOrProxy = eobjectDescription.getEObjectOrProxy();
            .....
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. It *does* work locally but not *globally*. I Googled, and found "Now names are forced to be unique. But only within a given object, we can reuse the same name across two different objects. We can see here that the name 'tom' is used in object 'a' and again in object 'b' without error. It can also be reused in different outer objects. Its only duplications within the same object that are prevented. " http://www.euclideanspace.com/software/development/eclipse/xtext/infrastructure/naming/index.htm

Comment: You can customize NamesAreUniqueValidationHelper for that purpose

Comment: This does not seem to be the case, Looking at the code in NamesAreUniqueValidator, it seems the exported objects of each object are themselves checked for uniqueness.     Iterable<IEObjectDescription> descriptions = description.getExportedObjects();
    helper.checkUniqueNames(descriptions, cancelIndicator, this);            -- I need to check for uniqueness amongst all objects.

Comment: I have to use the global index somehow?

Answer (score 2):

After much hacking, I obtained the following.

```
public static val GLOBALLY_DUPLICATE_NAME = 'GLOBALLY_DUPLICATE_NAME'

@com.google.inject.Inject
IResourceDescriptions iResourceDescriptions
@Inject
Provider<XtextResourceSet> resourceSetProvider;

@Check
def checkGreetingGloballyUnique(Greeting greeting) {
    for (resourceDescriptions : iResourceDescriptions.allResourceDescriptions) {
        for (_greetingDescription : resourceDescriptions.getExportedObjectsByType(MyDslPackage.Literals.GREETING)) {

            val _greeting = resourceSetProvider.get.getEObject(_greetingDescription.EObjectURI, true) as Greeting

            // don't use equality, ALWAYS not equal!!

            if (greeting.eResource.URI != _greeting.eResource.URI) {
                // this means distinct files, all greetings in same file have same uri
                if (greeting.name == _greeting.name) {
                    warning('Global greeting duplication', MyDslPackage.Literals.GREETING__NAME,
                        LOCALLY_DUPLICATE_NAME)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rewrite, based on @Christian Dietrich's comments, I have the following solution.

```
@Inject
    IContainer.Manager containerManager;
    @com.google.inject.Inject
    IResourceDescriptions resourceDescriptions
    @Inject
    Provider<XtextResourceSet> resourceSetProvider;

    @Check
    def checkGreetingGloballyUnique(Greeting greeting) {

        var greeting_description = resourceDescriptions.getResourceDescription(greeting.eResource.URI)
        var visibleContainers = containerManager.getVisibleContainers(greeting_description, resourceDescriptions)

        for (visibleContainer : visibleContainers) {
            for (_greetingDescription : visibleContainer.getExportedObjectsByType(MyDslPackage.Literals.GREETING)) {
                val _greeting = resourceSetProvider.get.getEObject(_greetingDescription.EObjectURI, true) as Greeting

                // don't use equality, ALWAYS greeting != _greeting !!
                if (greeting.eResource.URI != _greeting.eResource.URI) {
                    // this means distinct files, all greetings in same file have same uri
                    if (greeting.name == _greeting.name) {
                        warning('Global greeting duplication', MyDslPackage.Literals.GREETING__NAME,
                            GLOBALLY_DUPLICATE_NAME)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Am I using the global index appropriately/correctly?

Comment: no you dont you should use IContainer.Manager and visible containers too

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my solution based on your comment. Is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks for the help.